# Java - How to exit a method without return what he is expecting?

Tags: java, methods, exit

I've a method similar to the one bellow, where I want to return a private variable of one class only and only if, some conditions are verified. Otherwise I want to exit the method without return anything. I've tried something like the code bellow but I'm afraid that returning null is not a good idea. Are there any way to exit a method like the break keyword works for cycles?

```
private Classxpto classxpto;

public Classxpto getclassxpto(String abc, Date asd){
        String curr_abc= classxpto.getabc();
        Date curr_asd= classxpto.getasd();
            if("my conditions"){
                //dont return classxpto
                return null;
            }else if("my other conditions"){
                classxpto.setabc(abc);
                classxpto.setasd(asd);
                return classxpto;
            }
            return null;    
    }
```

Comment: `get` accessors shouldn't `set` values directly, use an event mechanism instead. It shouldn't control wether to `return` or not either. (except it's a security concern)

Comment: @AdamBrave Side comment: you might want to study some Java coding style guides - as your code really doesn't look like 99% of Java programmers would expect it to look like (esp. regarding Caseness of names)

Comment: I think what break for cycles is what return for method is.

Comment: @AbdullahShaikh and the equivalent to `continue` would be a recursive call? :)

Comment: If you want to indicate that there is no value to be returned then return null. null essentially just means "nothing". If it is an error to call the method unless those conditions are met, then throw an `Exception`. And by error I mean "this should never happen if everything is working correctly". Those are your only two options. I wouldn't recommend doing anything in between those two options as it will just cause problems on the long run.

Answer (score 5):

You can either return null (or some default `Classxpto` instance) or throw an exception. Throwing an exception is the only way to exit a method having a non-void return type without returning anything.

Comment: I should mention here that exceptions shouldn't be used to control the program flow!

Comment: Yes @Binkan is right. As soon as you start using `Exceptions` to control the program flow a lot of problems and bad code will follow. If you want to indicate that there is no value to be returned, then return null. If it is an actual error to call this method unless the conditions are satisfied - in other words of it should never happen if everything were working correctly - then throw an `Exception`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return "nothing" from a method unless it is declared as a `void` method.  (And in that case, you can *only* return "nothing"!)

The Java Language Specification says this in [§14.17](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17):

> A return statement with an Expression must be contained in one of the following, or a compile-time error occurs:
>
> - A method that is declared to return a value
> - ....

---

If you have no value to return, then your choices are either to pick some value that means (to your application) "no value", or throw an exception.

- The value `null` is often used to signify "no value", but you can use other things ... depending on the declared return type.
- Throwing an exception would a bad whay to deal with this, unless "no result" is truly an exceptional outcome.  Using exceptions and exception handling for normal flow control is a considered to be bad design in Java, and is liable to lead to serious performance problems.

<sup>It is also theoretically possible to terminate the JVM by calling `System.exit(...)`, or write the method so that it runs forever or goes to sleep forever.  However these are most likely "undesirable" behaviours.</sup>

Comment: Nothing wrong with `System.exit()`, wish java had a way to mark method as `noexit` though

Comment: In the context of *this* question and *this* answer, there is a LOT wrong with calling `System.exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always  throw the Exception

```
if(conditionNotMet){

throw new YourCustomException();

}
```

then Handle it in  whichever way you want !!!!

Comment: What would I put inside the exception? I just want to exit the method without returning anything.

Comment: @Adam Brave Then `thow`ing an exception is not the way you should take

Comment: @AdamBrave What you want is not possible. Either a method returns nothing (void); or if its signature says it should return a value - then you have to return a value OR throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

A method either return *nothing* (void), or *something* (including `null`), but can `throw` an `Exception`.

You have to think about *how* clients of the class will use the method. An exception really mean that the *no return* case should not occur in normal conditions.

Assuming the method is in a `Foo` class:

```
public class Foo {

   private ClassXPto classXPto;

   public ClassXPto getClassXPto() {...}

   // other Foo stuff
}
```

In the client code:

#### Returning `null`

```
Foo foo; // initialized somewhere    
ClassXPto x = foo.getClassXPto("abc", new Date());
if (x != null) {
   // do something with x
}
```

#### Throwing/catching an exception

```
Foo foo; // initialized somewhere    
try {
   ClassXPto x = foo.getClassXPto("abc", new Date());
   // do something with x
}
catch (WhatEverExceptionYouChoose e) {
   // process the exception
}
```

#### Propagating an exception

```
Foo foo; // initialized somewhere    
ClassXPto x = foo.getClassXPto("abc", new Date());
// do something with x. This point will be reached only
// if there is no exception thrown by getClassXPto()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your method is designed in such a way that the return parameter is optional, you could use the new **Optional** mechanisms in Java 8.

Instead of returning null you would return Optional.empty().

For more information visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html